# MapReduce Architecture

Tags: hadoop, architecture, hdfs, bigdata

I have created a diagram that represents how the MapReduce framework works. Could somebody please validate that this is an accurate representation?

[image: MapReduce Architecture]

P.S. For the purpose of this example, we are also interested in the system components shown in this diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The MapReduce Architecture works in various different phases for executing a job. Here are the different stages of running a MapReduce Application -

1. The first stage involves the user writing his data into the HDFS for further processing. This data is stored on different nodes in the form of blocks in the HDFS.
2. Now the client submits its MapReduce job.
3. Then, the resource manager launches a container to start the App master.
4. The App master sends a resource request to the resource manager.
5. The resource manager now allocates containers on slaves via the node manager.
6. The App master starts respective tasks in the containers.
7. The job is now been executed in the container.
8. When the processing is complete, the resource manager deallocates the resources.

[image: This GIF will surely help in understanding things better]

Source: [Cloudera](https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/introduction-to-yarn-and-mapreduce-2)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for your input, please be so kind - edit your question and name your sources.

Answer (score 0):

JobTracker, TaskTracker, and MasterNode aren't real things in Hadoop 2+ w/ YARN. Jobs are submitted to a **ResourceManager**, which creates an **ApplicationMaster** on one of the **NodeManager**s.

"Slave Nodes" are commonly also your DataNodes because that is the core tenant of Hadoop - move the processing *to the data*.

The "Recieve the data" arrow is bi-directional, and there is no arrow from the NameNode to the DataNode. 1) Get the file locations from the NameNode, then locations are sent back to clients. 2) The clients (i.e. NodeManager processes running on a DataNode, or "slave nodes"), will directly read from the DataNodes themselves - the datanodes don't know directly where the other slave nodes exist.

That being said, HDFS and YARN are typically all part of the same "bubble", so the "HDFS" labelled circle you have should really be around everything.